# Insert into another table after manipulations

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables with same structures in two different databases.
Now, I want to copy the contents from one table (say table1 of db1) into another table (say table2 of db2), but I want to perform certain manipulations of some of the columns before inserting.

For example if table1 of db1 has 50 columns, I want to manipulate some (say 5) columns and insert the rest as is

Following is what I have done.
I am writing a pl/sql script declaring as many variables as the table columns
then a cursor to select from table
and then iterating in a loop to perform manipulations on individual columns and inserting into table2

```
DECLARE
var1   datatype;
var2   datatype;
..

CURSOR MY_CUR is
SELECT * FROM table1;

BEGIN
FOR CUR_ROW in MY_CUR
LOOP
    var1 := CUR_ROW.column1
    var2 := CUR_ROW.column2
    ..
    logic to modify some variables e.g. var1 := LPAD(var1,5,'1');
    ..
insert into table2@db2
(column1, column2 ..)
values
(var1, var2 ..);
END LOOP;
END;
```

This is very slow, is there any other efficient way to accomplish this?
(perhaps BULK COLLECT or FORALL?) but using BULK COLLECT or FORALL, how could I perform manipulations on individual columns?

I am using Oracle10g

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use a single SQL statement (`insert into t2@db2( col1, col2, ... ) select lpad(col1,5,'1'), ... from t1`)?

Comment: It depends on what manipulations you want to do. Some of them, like LPAD can be done using SQL functions. You can just say select lpad(var1) in your cursor definition. Some may require procedural logic.

Comment: Yes, as I have to do multiple manipulations which requires checking of variables in IF ELSIF and involve other loops to be implemented over the variables. the LPAD was just an example to illustrate that I want to do certain manipulations on variables. Thanks.

Comment: A pipelined function would probably be faster, but I would first look for a way of using pure SQL, or second for SQL with embedded PL/SQL functions, instead of the row-by-row approach.

Answer (score 0):

try to do one more thing build the collection using for loop which you are doing then insert it with bulk insert statement. first declare collection with row type of table which is used for insert.  eg.

```
   type table2_typ is table of  table2@db2%rowtype
   v_table2_typ  table2_typ;
```

fill collection v_table2_typ in you basic for loop and then insert this using bulk collect insert  eg.

```
FORALL i IN 1..v_table2_typ.COUNT
 INSERT INTO t1 VALUES v_table2_typ(i);
```

you need to use limit clause and commit mechanism if your data volume is more.